# Django 1.7 - migrations from South

Tags: python, django, django-south

I have a project based on Django 1.6 with South. I wonder is it possible to upgrade my project to Django 1.7 with new built-in database migration system and save possibility to downgrade database to previous statements?

Comment: You should read the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south

Comment: I know about it. As I understand, after actions, described in docs, it will be impossible to downgrade database to previous states (using parameter with migration number for migrate command).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a blog post I can't find anymore, the best way is to create two distinct directories:
one new_migrations which will handle the migrations files (django 1.7), and another one old_migrations which will handle (if you need to) the downgrade part.

In order to do it, move your migrations folder to old_migrations, then recreate all your schema with the migrations built-in :)

In case of downgrade, just move your old directory and use South as before.